# Why does the tag `kali-linux-tools` even exist? It would help if it were removed

Tags: discussion

In my 1½ year here, I don't think I've ever seen the tag [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools) used correctly. People usually use this tag when asking about Kali Linux, which will then be closed. And there already is a tag [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin) for the script that helps install Kali Tools on Ubuntu.

In my opinion, this tag adds more confusion than it solves, so removing/blocking it would probably help with new users not using it correctly.

Also, the description is pretty vague: *"Kali Linux Tools can be a synonym for Katoolin ..."*. But what else can it be? The options for misuse are endless...

Comment: The same reason Mint tag exists... it is a trap to catch topics... filter on them and you have a 90% chance the topic can be closed as "not about official Ubuntu" :D

Comment: When **kali-linux-tools** are installed in Ubuntu, they are by definition a **Ubuntu Third Party App**. According to Ask Ubuntu Help, Ubuntu **Third Party Apps are On-Topic** in Ask Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. I see no reason to reduce the number of people that Ask Ubuntu serves. Seems like everyone wants to make their own rules around here.

Comment: I'm not opposed to supporting questions about Katoolin (Kali Tools) if the tag is used correctly. My point is that currently, the tag is almost never used correctly. So if it's to be used, I guess the description should be updated to be much more precise.

Comment: "the description should be updated to be much more precise" that rarely (read never) works.

Comment: @Braiam Did you read down to the answer, which details the edit that I suggested and is now in effect?

Comment: Is not a problem with the edit itself, is that people _literally_ don't read it. It could be perfect for the people that reads it, but those are already aware that there's information to be found there and would not misuse the tag. Editing the tag excerpt is not the solution.

Comment: Fair point :-D In that case, I'm not sure what would solve it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been resolved by edits that were made to the [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools) tag by Artur Meinild.

*EDIT: Added the following - Artur*

The suggested change focused more on what Kali Linux tools (and Katoolin3 script) is, and why it differs from the Kali Linux distribution.

The following text were added:

> Kali Linux contains a large amount of penetration testing tools from
> various different niches of the security and forensics fields. Many of
> these can be installed and used on Ubuntu.
>
> [Kali Linux Tools](https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing) is a suite of software that can either be
> installed manually from the Kali Linux page or with the [Katoolin3](https://github.com/s-h-3-l-l/katoolin3)
> script. Installing and using Kali Linux Tools on Ubuntu is largely
> unsupported, can break your system and will require some knowledge of
> the end user.